# What's the difference between Job Title and employer relationship description?

Tags: contacts

The "Current Employer" field seems to be a helper for entering a "Employee of" relationship. Fair enough (although presumably designed back in the good ol' days when the majority of people only had one job).

But the Job Title - which presumably relates to the "Current Employer" does not seem linked to the "Description" field of the "Employee of" relationship; it seems to be a separate field?

Does anyone know how these parts are expected to interact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, there is no connection between the "Current Employer" field and the "Job Title" field.

If you select a contact in the "Current Employer" Field it will also create a relationship AND disable an existing "employer relationship" which is marked as "current employer".

If you create a "employer relationship" you will have a little checkbox that says "current employer". If you tick it, it will also fill the "Current Employer" field and uncheck "current employer" with the existing "employer relationship" (but not disable it).

By the way, if you share an address you also have the option to "Set this organization as current employer" - which effects I do not know from the top of my head.

All this "UI magic" has been introduced / revised a while ago and has confused me plenty. It can also be quite complicated when you try to use the API (e.g. for imports) as the "current employer" attribute is not availbale there (at least to my limited knowledge).

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Thanks so much Fabian! It was one of those "beginner questions" that I had after 10 years working with CiviCRM! I find the magic bits difficult, though I like the nod to user-convenience in theory.

Comment: It might be a bit less "magic" if these nuances where properly documented.

Comment: @fabian, did you mean to say there is "No" connection between employer and job title? That's what I see.

Comment: @AndyBurns Yes, thanks I fixed it in the answer